# SDL_DisplayFormat not declared in this scope: Using SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Compiler doesn't return missing SDL.h, but rather that SDL_DisplayFormat is not declared in scope of a class member function located on a different header even though I have it initialized in main.

```
SDL_Surface *SpriteLoad::Load(char *File)
{
    SDL_Surface *temp = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *opt = NULL;

    if ((temp = IMG_Load(File)) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    opt = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

    return opt;
}
```

Where my main inits SDL through a class and member function:

```
int main (int args, char *argc[])
{
    bool quit = false;

    OnRun Game;           // Class that init's SDL
    Window TestWin;

    GlobalTimer fps;
    TestWin.Debug();
```

I'm able to create a window using SDL_Window using that Class and also use SDL_GetTick.

EDIT: Headers used for Sprite::Load are currently SDL, SDL_image, SDL_ttf, and SDL_mixer pulled and built from the mercurial repo. I do not think it's a linking error though

Comment: Can you add what headers get included for the .cpp file defining `SpriteLoad::Load`.

Comment: Updated what I used in `Sprite::Load`

Comment: Is there anything in the .cpp that could modify the namespace of `SDL_DisplayFormat` when it gets included?

Comment: What do you mean? I never declared using a namespace. Here's a link to what's currently written in the header: [spriteload](http://pastebin.com/YBsB46H9). Where `mains.h` are standard libs and SDL and `init.h` is where the class init'ing SDL is.

Comment: Can you also include what `mains.h` and `init.h` looks like in pastebin?

Comment: [mains.h](http://pastebin.com/YXczERh7) and [init.h](http://pastebin.com/PV6r785X). I was thinking that it could be that SDL was not being initialized for `Sprite::Load` but then if it hadn't it wouldn't be initialized for any other function using SDL that would require SDL_Init for them to actually be used, such as SDL_Window and SDL_GetTick.

Comment: Also where `OnRun Game;` is called refers to [onrun.h](http://pastebin.com/5Unbk7Vr)

Comment: The error message is essentially saying the compiler can't find `SDL_DisplayFormat`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason you're getting that compiler error is because `SDL_DisplayFormat` no longer exist in SDL-2.0.

After looking at the **[SDL wiki doc](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SGFunctions%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29)** it appears `SDL_DisplayFormat` from SDL-1.2 has been replaced by `SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat` in SDL-2.0.

Comment: Just came back and was about to edit the post. Looking through SDL I found no trace on `SDL_DisplayFormat`, though I couldn't find any documentation on it's removal. Thanks for all your help and linking me documentation!

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your code as follows for SDL 2.0;

```
SDL_Surface *SpriteLoad::Load(SDL_Window *window, char *File)
{
    SDL_Surface *temp = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *opt = NULL;

    if ((temp = IMG_Load(File)) == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // If the window wasn't created yet, just return the texture
    if(window == NULL) return temp;

    opt = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(temp, SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat(window), 0);
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

    return opt;
}
```

In my own code I return the image unoptimized if there is no window created yet (I sometimes use this for a splash screen before the window).  But you could change this so that it free's temp and returns NULL if that is important for you, perhaps with a warning to create a window first.